# updateUrl() always redirects to the starting page URL and not to the specific page

Tags: javascript, python, datatables

I have a flask app and I try to load my table copying URL on browser.
For example, when I use table pagination URL is builded like this

```
http://localhost:5000/?length=5&page=5
http://localhost:5000/?length=5&page=6
...
```

When I try to load the page directly from these URLs a problem occurs: the table is always loaded from its starting address `http://localhost:5000/?length=5&page=1` regardless of the page specified in the URL

`&page=5` or `&page=6` or other pages are completely ignored so the data is not loaded to that specific page

My current code that handles everything is this javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    var lengthParam = parseInt(urlParams.get('length'));  
    var startParam = parseInt(urlParams.get('start'));
    if (!isNaN(startParam) && startParam >= 0) {
        dataTable.page(parseInt(startParam / lengthParam)).draw();
    }

    var dataTable = $('#userTable').DataTable({
        ajax: {
            url: '/search',
            data: function (d) {
                d.searchTerm = $('#userTable_filter input').val();
                d.length = d.length || lengthParam;  // Aggiungi questa linea
                d.page = d.start / d.length;
                d.start = urlParams.get('start') || d.start;
            }
        },

        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        lengthMenu: [5, 10, 25, 100, 500],
        "columns": [
            {data: 'id'},
            {data: 'username'},
            {data: 'badge'},
            {data: 'extra'}
        ],
    });

    // Add an event listener for the DataTables event that occurs when the search term changes
    $('#userTable').on('search.dt', function() {
        updateUrl();
    });

    // Add an event listener for the DataTables event that occurs when the number of displayed entries changes
    $('#userTable').on('length.dt', function() {
        updateUrl();
    });

    // Add an event listener for the DataTables event that occurs when the page changes
    $('#userTable').on('page.dt', function() {
        updateUrl();
    });

    function updateUrl() {
        var searchTerm = $('#userTable_filter input').val();
        var length = $('#userTable_length select').val();
        var page = dataTable.page.info().page;
    
        var url = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
        var params = [];
    
        if (searchTerm) {
            params.push('search=' + encodeURIComponent(searchTerm));
        }
    
        if (length) {  // Modifica questa condizione
            params.push('length=' + encodeURIComponent(length));
        }
    
        params.push('page=' + encodeURIComponent(page + 1));
    
        if (params.length > 0) {
            url += '?' + params.join('&');
        }
    
        history.replaceState({}, '', url);
    }


    // Check if there are parameters in the query string at startup
    var searchParam = urlParams.get('search');
    

    if (searchParam) {
        $('#userTable_filter input').val(decodeURIComponent(searchParam));
        dataTable.search(decodeURIComponent(searchParam)).draw();
    }

    if (lengthParam) {
        $('#userTable_length select').val(decodeURIComponent(lengthParam));
        dataTable.page.len(decodeURIComponent(lengthParam)).draw();
    }

    if (startParam) {
        dataTable.page(parseInt(startParam / lengthParam)).draw();
    }

    // Check if there are parameters in the query string at startup
    var pageParam = parseInt(urlParams.get('page'));
    if (!isNaN(pageParam) && pageParam >= 0) {
        dataTable.page(pageParam).draw();
    }

});
```

I think the problem is in the `updateUrl()` function, in my python code I don't see any particular problems

```
@app.route('/search', methods=['GET'])
def search_data():
    try:
        search_term = request.args.get('search[value]')
        start = int(request.args.get('start', 0))
        length = int(request.args.get('length', 5))
        order_column = int(request.args.get('order[0][column]'))
        order_dir = request.args.get('order[0][dir]')
 
... [other code]
```